# Is there a way to simulate "strongdef"?

Tags: c++, typedef

As you probably know typedef is more like an alias in C++ not a new type, details can be seen here:
http://dlang.org/cpptod.html#typedefs
I really dont like the solution proposed in the link, so Im wondering is there a better way ?

Comment: I have to agree that C/C++ have a big problem with typing. Some other languages such as Ada have a much better scheme in that regard. You should not be able to add 3 carrots to 3 potatoes even if both are represented by an integer.

Answer (score 7):

There is only one way to introduce a new type in C++ -with a class keyword (`union`/`struct`/`class`/`enum`...). There are ways to hide this stuff behind macros and make those new types as intuitively usable as the old ones (see [`BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF`](http://www.boost.org/libs/serialization/doc/strong_typedef.html)), but the fact remains that it's the only way to introduce this new type.

Imagine you had a `newtype` keyword that makes a strong typedef:

```
newtype foo = int; // with 'using' alias syntax
```

How would conversions to and from that type work? With no conversions, you could never assign any value to an object of your new type. Only explicit conversions might seem intuitive, but what if you *really* want implicit conversions, and still be able to overload? Well, tough luck. You might be able to add all kinds of syntax to leave the decision to the user, but I'm sure you can always come up with corner cases that would need new syntax. Just make it a `struct`, hide it behind a macro and be done with it.

Comment: The second paragraph describes a solved problem, really. You could for instance have a syntax such as `newtype foo = narrowing<int>` along with `widening<>`, `distinct<>`, `explicit<>` and more combinations. Other programming languages do in fact have such features.

Comment: @Konrad: And why not just `using foo = narrowing<int, struct _foo_int_key>` (which is basically what `BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF` does behind the scenes) if you're already going the route of having special template-like things to specify the conversion? It can be done employing the language itself, so I see no *big* reason to integrate it into the core language

Comment: It can’t be done. Boost only does it for primitive types and I’m sure that there is *no* way of doing it automatically for any types with member functions. You can lift operators – you cannot, in principle, lift member functions.

Comment: Oh, is `BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF` really only for built-in types? I overlooked that part. Let me edit.

Comment: how to I access underlying type, for example BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF(std::string, name); name n; how do i .resize() n?

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: As was said, `BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF` is only intended for fundamental types, aka `int`, `bool`, `char`, etc. I'll edit code with a solution in a bit.

Comment: @Xeo - did you gave up on trying to do general solution? If you are just tell me so I dont keep rechecking the answer for edits.  :)

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: No I didn't, but I had some stuff come up with my solution that I'd like to resolve first. :) Basically, my solution is to either have the type as a member if it's a built-in type, or inherit from it if it's not. Through the public inheritance, you get all the member functions lifted. The downside is, of course, that you have implicit conversions to the original type that cannot be restricted. :/ Also, I'll @ notify you when I edit the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Generic "no time to make a proper interface" macro:

```
#define STRONG_CLASS_TYPEDEF(oldType, newType) \
struct newType : private oldType {             \
    template<typename... T>                    \
    newType(T... foo) : oldType(foo...) {}     \
    oldType* operator->() { return this; }     \
    oldType& operator*() {return *this;}       \
};
```

If your compiler doesn't support variadic templates, you'll need to manually insert whatever constructors you need instead. That is basically a build-your-own inheriting constructor.

Unfortunately I don't think it is possible to restrict the new type implicitly casting to the base, but expose all of its public fields. There are a few workarounds:

You can just `using oldType::X;` all of the methods and variables you need. This is definitely the best solution, but takes a while to do.

Or use the sneaky arrow operator overload and call `foo->method();`. Or "dereference" the new strong type into the base type. These are basically just a fancy explicit cast. But considering `operator oldType()` (explicit or not) doesn't even work with private inheritance...

Anyway, here's a strong type for the `std::string` and `Name` example.

```
struct Name : private std::string {
    template<typename... T>
    Name(T... foo) : std::string(foo...) {}

    std::string* operator->() { return this; }
    const std::string& operator*() {return *this;}
    //The above is obviously a bad idea if you want to use this alongside pointers

    using std::string::resize;
    using std::string::size;
    using std::string::insert;
    using std::string::operator[];
    // etc.
    //Simplest to use, but a bit more to set up
};
```

Also, you'll have to wrap the non-member operator overloads (std::string `==` in this example).

```
bool operator==(Name& lhs, Name& rhs) { return *lhs == *rhs; }
//Note: "Dereference" turns it into a std::string, as above
```

Fair warning, I haven't tested much beyond basic mechanics. It might add a (very) small amount of overhead. But the effectively empty class is *probably* optimized away.

Comment: having lots of `using` breaks the purpose of strong typedef, since it should be simple. You might add a public reference to the base class, but still, what to do with functions, like operator==?

Comment: @BЈовић

I addressed the `operator==` thing in my answer at the bottom.

And yes, `using` is rather verbose. But it doesn't defeat the purpose because it still doesn't allow conversion to the base class.

I'm not sure what you mean by a "public reference to the base class". If you mean public inheritance, then that defeats the purpose of a **strong** typedef because that allows implicit conversion to the base.

Comment: Like this :`struct Name : private std::string { std::string& t; };`.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Assuming you just have it reference itself then that could easily work. It's also a lot cleaner than overloading.

Comment: I think that is a way boost implemented BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF.

Answer (score 1):

Use `BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF` to create "strongdefs" in C++. There is no built-in language feature to do so.

That said it would be interesting to know the real problem you're trying to solve because I've found the need for non-alias `typedef`s to be very minimal across code I've worked on.

Comment: it is pretty much to make harder for ppl to mess up :) eg.  functions that  fwd first second and fifth string passed to them to another function.  :D

Answer (score 0):

New types in C++ can result only by somehow aggregating subtypes. But since function overloading is based on the static type, all operation and function must be redeclared.

C++ `typedef`s are like D `alias`es.

In case the starting type is a class or struct, inheritance can somehow help (at least operations can still work as with old parameters) but everything is about return type and conversion must be redefined properly, otherwise everything converts indifferently up and down, thus vanishing the advantage of a new type.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways in C++ to perform type checking. 
Consider the following code, the basic idea is the same as the example given in the link, but I think it is more straightforward:

```
struct Handle2 {void * ptr;} ;
void bar(Handle2) {}
void foo(void *) {}

int main() {
    Handle2 h2 = {(void*)-1};
    foo(h2); //! won't pass through compiling
    bar(h2);
}
```